# Compiler error in default parameters in class

Tags: c++, class, optional-parameters

I'm trying to pass the second argument optional to my search function:

```
class ExponentialTree
{
public:
node* Search(int num, node* curr_node=root);
void Insert(int num);

private:
node* root;
};

node* ExponentialTree::Search(int num, node* curr_node)
{
```

If I call with one parameter, I want it to set it to root. I tried defult parameter in declaration, default parameter in implementation, both(I know its not true), two declaration. Nothing worked. Any ideas? I don't want overloading method beacuse it is the only line that will change.

Thanks.

Comment: root is not visible from outside

Comment: AFAIK, the only option it to make an overload of `Search` without that parameter.

Comment: Try to set it as `NULL` and then in the first run set it to `root`.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
    node* Search(int num, node* curr_node=NULL);
```

and handle the case of NULL pointer in the body of the function:

```
    node* Search(int num, node* curr_node)
    {
         if (curr_node == NULL){
               //...
         }
         //...
    }
```

Or it can be set in the implementation part too, but just with NULL.

Comment: Nice one! What is the source of the problem? Does the compiler only recognizes constant or enumerated values?

Answer (score 1):

A non-static member variable can not be used as a default argument.

Below is the relevant section in `C++ standard draft (N3225), section § 8.3.6, point 9:`

```
.. a non-static member shall not be used in a default argument expression, even if it
is not evaluated, unless it appears as the id-expression of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless
it is used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1). [ Example: the declaration of X::mem1() in the following
example is ill-formed because no object is supplied for the non-static member X::a used as an initializer.
int b;
class X {
int a;
int mem1(int i = a); // error: non-static member a
// used as default argument
int mem2(int i = b); // OK; use X::b
static int b;
};
```

`root` is a non-static member variable here -- hence you can not specify it as a default argument.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of where you actually **would gain** from using an overload:

```
node* Search(int num, node* curr_node) 
{
   // Your implementation
}
```

and then

```
inline node* Search(int num) { return Search(num, root); }
```

Hereby you explicitly state, that when *no parameter is given*, you should use `root` as the value for `curr_node`.

There is no need to make a runtime test, when the code can be decided at compile time, and you don't have to write `NULL` when you actually mean `root`.

Comment: Can I write inline method in class definition?